table.row.add(newRow).draw(false); inserting table within table in asp.net c# razor view
in my asp.net core project there is index.cshtml page in which i am making ajax call to controller action:
$(document).on('click', '.openFormData', function () {
    //debugger;
    var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/OpenUserData',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'id': dataId },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main').html(data);
        },
        error: function (e, v) {
            console.log('Error occurred:', e);
            alert('Error occurred: ', e.status + ': ' + e.statusText);
        }
    });
}); 

in success function the controller is returning view :
public async Task<IActionResult> OpenUserData(Guid id)
        {
            CreateUpdateUserRequest request = new CreateUpdateUserRequest();


            if (id != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var route = "GetUserDetailsByUserId?UserId=" + id;
                var response = await DataHelper<CreateUpdateUserRequest>.Execute(route, OperationTypes.GET, null);
                if (response != null && response.Data != null)
                {
                    request = response.Data;
                }
            }

            

            return View("UserInformation", request);
        }

now in my UserInformation.cshtml i have used jquery datatable:
<table id="add-data" class="display table table-striped table-hover"> 

and i am adding row to this datatable:
$("#addNewUser").click(function (e) {
    //debugger;
    const table = $('#add-data').DataTable();
    var newRow = [
    `<a  class="edit-data" ' title="Edit" ><i class="fas fa-edit" style="font-size: 18px; color: green;"></i></a>
    <a class="remove-data" ' title="Delete" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="font-size: 18px; color: red;"></i></a>`,
    'value'
];
    table.row.add(newRow).draw(false);
}

which inserts table within table instead of only inserting single row. How can i prevent inserting table within table and insert only single row with some value? and getting error: "**DataTables warning: table id=add-room - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4**" at the time of assigning table :const table = $('#add-room').DataTable();

I followed this document and add a row to rendered datatable. It gives us a sample
var table = new DataTable('#myTable');
 
table.row
    .add({
        name: 'Tiger Nixon',
        position: 'System Architect',
        salary: '$3,120',
        start_date: '2011/04/25',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        extn: '5421'
    })
    .draw();

Then here's my code:
<table id="table1" class="display table-bordered"
       style="width:100%">
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add row</button>

@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var maintable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            maintable =  $('#table1').DataTable({
                select: {
                    style: 'multi'
                },
                ajax: {
                    "url": "/table/LoadStuds",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataSrc": function (myJson) {
                        console.info(myJson)
                        return myJson;
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'studID', title: 'StudID', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'studCode', title: 'Stud Code', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'classNo', title: 'Class No', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'teacher', title: 'Teachere', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'remarks', title: 'Remarks', autoWidth: true },
                ]
            });
        });

        $('#addRow').click(function () {
            // var table = new DataTable('#table1');

            maintable.row
                .add({
                    studID: 'added id',
                    studCode: 'added code',
                    classNo: 'added number',
                    teacher: 'added teacher',
                    remarks: 'added remark'
                })
                .draw();
        });
    </script>
}


